# How to test HTTP to HTTPS tunneling with Casper.js?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I've got to get test coverage on some of our company's extranet, we are using phantom.js/casper.js since it has been the easiest to integrate with the rest of our testing work flow.

The problem arises when attempting to transition from HTTP to HTTPS via tunneling. If a users were to go to our website at http//www.somecompany.com and click on the login link their browser redirects to https//extranet.somecompany.com. If you were to look at the HTML source you would see the HTML that correctly corresponds to the form the user was redirected to.

However, when attempting to recreate the workflow with casper.js I successfully initiate the click event on the login link. I then attempt to identify a form element to confirm that the redirect was successful, but this test fails. I then modified my next step after redirect to do a capture of the page to see what casper "sees". When I open the image the HTML appears as if I had never been redirected. I know that the redirect is working because I see the traffic in Fiddler which shows the tunnel being established to port 443.

I've searched SO, google, and the Casper google group and can't find much regarding a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, is Casper/Phantom capable of automating a workflow like this or will I have to look at something like Selenium?

Comment: Have you tried passing `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` to the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Redirection works out of the box in PhantomJS 1.9.8. If unsure feel free to debug using:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
  console.log('Response ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};
```

You should see in your first response sth like:

```
"redirectURL": "https//extranet.somecompany.com",
```